# Is it possible to have a list of patterns and exp applied to match?

Tags: design-patterns, racket, matching

I want to use the function `match` in Racket to get the first element for which exp0 gives a true.

```
(define mylist '(['c c] ['a a] ['* *]))

(match '* mylist))
```

But that doesn't work. It throws an error "expected a clause with a pattern and a result". How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First, you have a small problem; I really don't think you want to be quoting your keys inside a quoted list; that's going to produce keys that are actually lists containing the symbol "quote". Basically, just don't put a quote inside a quote.)

Next: you might be looking for one of several different things.

The first and most obvious answer is just to use something like `dict-ref`:

```
#lang racket

(define mylist '([c c] [a a] [* *]))

(dict-ref mylist '*)
```

... which produces the list `'(*)`. You can read the docs on dict-ref to see why it's a list.

This will work fine up until you actually want to use the richer matching semantics that `match` gives you. If you just want to match using equality, just use the solution above.

So, let's say you're looking for a key consisting of the letter 'a followed by a number:

```
#lang racket

(define mylist
  '([(c b) c]
    [(a 3) a]
    [(* *) *]))

(findf (match-lambda [(list (list 'a (? number?)) _) #t]
                     [other #f])
       mylist)
```